# SQL Query matching tables(allocation)

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

Ok So Here is my database extract

```
customers- ID, Fname, LName, Username, Password
Products - ProductsID, Name
Requests - requestid, productsid[fk for products table], cid[fk for customers table],
quantity, matchType
sellers - saleid, productsid[fk for products table], cid[fk for customers table], quantity
price.
```

So they are my tables with FK denoting foreign keys... Now the problem I am having is say this is an extract from the table values

```
customers=1,John,Smith,js123,123
customers=2,Joe,bloggs,jb555,abc
products=1,Sweets
products=2, chocolate
requests=1, 2, 1, 200, Exact
requests=2, 1, 1, 50, HighQuality
sellers =1,2,2,200,5.00
```

ok so what is going on here is we have 2 customers and 2 products(sweets and chcolates), the requests table shows.. the requestid [primary key], product id, the customers id who has requested the product, the quantity in grams and how they want matches to be displayed.
So, if we take the first request it would read as follows... REquestID 1[pk], wants chcolates(2), the user who wants choclates is john smith and he wants 200 grams worth that is exactly matched to his request... 
Now we have a seller namely, joe bloggs who is selling chcolates for 200 grams at £5.00... 
Now the issue I am having is how do I run a query that matches this seller to the appropriate customer. i.e. lists the seller name based on the customers matchTYpe(pre-fences) This is what I have tried:

```
select c.Fname, c.Lname, p.Name FROM customers c, Products p, Requests, sellers 
WHERE c.ID=sellers.cid AND p.ProductsID=sellers.productsid
```

This would list all the seller names and the name of products they are selling. However, I wish to display only those products where in the requests table the word is EXACT..hence only matches exact quantities. So, I tried:

```
select c.Fname, c.Lname, p.Name FROM customers c, Products p, Requests, sellers 
WHERE c.ID=sellers.cid AND p.ProductsID=sellers.productsid  
AND Requests.productsid=sellers.productid AND Requests.matchType ='Exact'
```

I have tried this and this does not output correctly what I want. How do I fix it I want my output to be:

```
joe,bloggs,choclates
```

So this matches requestid 1 where. However I just cant get this output can someone pelase help me? Surely, by matching the products.id with sellers.productsid would show the name and then by matching the requests.productid with seller.productid WHERE requests.matchType='Exact' it should work? but it dont show that output that I expect.

Comment: You showed the output you want.  What is the output you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

When matchType is exact then request.Quantity = sellers.quantity. So i guess your where clause should be

```
WHERE c.ID=sellers.cid 
  AND p.ProductsID=sellers.productsid  
  AND Requests.productsid=sellers.productid 
  AND CASE WHEN Requests.matchType ='Exact' THEN sellers.quantity
           ELSE -1 END = CASE WHEN Requests.matchType ='Exact' THEN Requests.quantity
                              ELSE -1 END
```

OR

```
WHERE c.ID=sellers.cid 
  AND p.ProductsID=sellers.productsid  
  AND Requests.productsid=sellers.productid 
  AND ((Requests.matchType ='Exact' AND sellers.quantity = Requests.quantity)
       OR Requests.matchType != 'Exact')
```